# How do we use articles when we speak about something abstract?

Tags: articles

I know that we use "the" article when we speak about something general, right?
But I just saw this sentence:

> "Carrying six heavy bags will impede your progress if you're trying to walk across town in a hurry."

Isn't "town" a general idea?
I'm struggling with articles, would be great if you could show a couple of examples.

Comment: _Town_ is a locational term meaning 'the town that you live in', just as _home_ means 'the place you live' and _school_ means 'whatever school is attended in context'. All of these and other words appear without articles (or with them): _She's in town, just back from school, and wanted to know whether you were home._

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't there a "the" in "I left work", but there is in "I left the office"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/401207/why-isnt-there-a-the-in-i-left-work-but-there-is-in-i-left-the-office)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“I had a flat in the centre of town, but I didn’t like living there, so …”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/199407/i-had-a-flat-in-the-centre-of-town-but-i-didn-t-like-living-there-so)

Comment: @JohnLawle, So it's more like an exception, with all of those locational terms. I get it.
Thank you sooo much, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I expect there's a *reason*, but I don't know why ***home / work = the place where you live / work*** doesn't work *exactly* the same as ***town = the town you live in***. I'm quite happy with or without the article in ***I'm in [the] town***, but there are few contexts where ***I'm at the home*** is acceptable, and none at all for ***I'm at the work***.

Comment: I think **town** itself is a little tricky, but anyway I'm used to English being so English with all its exceptions. I'll just try to find more cases like these.

Comment: Why do you think that *we use "the" article when we speak about something general*? That seems like a gross oversimplification. Did you read it somewhere?

Comment: I remember that at first I was confused with **"The lion is a fierce animal"**, and tried to find out why we use **the**, and yeah, I saw this explanation a couple of times somewhere. Now I see that I was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that the definite article "the" is often used for a general statement, there are many cases where no article is used, and some where an indefinite article "a" is used; there does not seem any clear pattern of which is used in what case, no rule to cite. A few examples:

> - The sea is often perceived as calm and nurturing, but also as fierce and cruel.
> - Wind is invisible, but palpable, and often serves as a literary symbol.
> - A way of life is hard to summarize, but important to one's basic evaluations.
> - The sky is seen as having many different colors under different conditions.
> - Love is something  many experience, but few can define well.
> - A mathematical description of a phenomenon can be essential to predictability, but often it does not convey the human experience involved.

In short, a general idea may be shown by any article or none, depending on the specific phrase and its history of usage.

"*Trying to walk across town*" can mean any urban area in general, or the specific but unstated area where the speaker or audience lives. In either case no article is used. The similar phrase "*trying to walk across the town*" would more often refer to a specific area, although it might be unstated and implied.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the examples!